# One record print two times in table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter framework and performing some query in this.
When I fetch record from data base its return double record. I'm trying like following code

This is my controller code:

```
public function fetchDue(){

      $due         = $this->input->post('due_to');
      $br          = $this->session->userdata('user_branch');
      $modelResult = $this->DDModel->fetchDue($due,$br);


      ?>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="row">
        <table id="cash_memo_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="display:block; overflow: auto; ">

                    <tr>
                      <th>mr_no</th>
                      <th>bilty_no</th>
                      <th>Bilty Date</th>
                      <th>Weight</th>
                      <th>Total</th> 
                      <th>Create/Update</th>
                    </tr>


      <?php foreach ($modelResult as $due) : 

       for($i=0; $i< count($modelResult); $i++){
          $vfDueResult = $this->DDModel->verifyFetchDue($modelResult[$i]->mr_no);
           if($vfDueResult==1){
            ?>

            <?php

          }else if($vfDueResult==0){
              $verifyRemainingFetchDue  = $this->DDModel->verifyRemainingFetchDue($modelResult[$i]->mr_no);
              if($verifyRemainingFetchDue==1){
                $modelResult = $this->DDModel->fetchDDRRecord($modelResult[$i]->mr_no);

                ?>
                    <tr>

                      <td><?php echo $due->mr_no; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->mr_no; ?>" name="mr_no[]">
                      <td><?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?>" name="bilty_no[]">
                      <td><?php echo $due->lr_date; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_date; ?>" name="lr_date[]">
                      <td><?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight ; ?></td> 
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight; ?>" name="lr_actual_weight[]">
                      <td><input type="hidden" class="cal" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $due->total; ?>"><?php echo $due->total; ?></td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-update" id="update">Update</button></td>
                    </tr> 
                    <?php

                }else{

                   ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $due->mr_no; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->mr_no; ?>" name="mr_no[]">
                      <td><?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?>" name="bilty_no[]">
                      <td><?php echo $due->lr_date; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_date; ?>" name="lr_date[]">
                      <td><?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight ; ?></td> 
                          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight; ?>" name="lr_actual_weight[]">
                      <td><input type="hidden" class="cal" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $due->total; ?>"><?php echo $due->total; ?></td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-insert" id="insert">Insert</button></td>
                    </tr> 
            <?php 
               }//else end
          }
       }
      ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form> 
    <?php
    }
```

This is my Model code:

```
  function fetchDue($due,$br){

             $usertype= $this->db->select('user_reg_type')->from('ts_users')->where('user_id',$due)->get()->result_array(); 
             $user = $usertype[0]['user_reg_type'];

             if($user == "consignor"){

          return   $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('crossing_cash_memo')
                        ->where('lr_from',$br)
                        ->where('consignor_name',$due)
                        ->get()->result();

             }elseif($user == "consignee"){

                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('crossing_cash_memo');
                $this->db->where('lr_from',$br);
                $this->db->where('consignee_name',$due);

                  $query = $this->db->get();
                  return $query->result();
             }
        }

 function verifyFetchDue($mRNo){
      $query = $this->db->select('*')
               ->from('delivery_due_received')
               ->where('mr_no',$mRNo)
               ->where('g_total=0')
               ->get()
               ->num_rows();
            return $query;
    }


    function verifyRemainingFetchDue($mRNo){
      $query = $this->db->select('*')
               ->from('delivery_due_received')
               ->where('mr_no',$mRNo)
               ->where('g_total != 0')
               ->get()
               ->num_rows();
            return $query;
    }

     function fetchDDRRecord($mr_no){

                    return   $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('delivery_due_received')
                    ->where('mr_no',$mr_no)
                    ->get()->result_array();
                }
```

I am performing some condition in this for verify record is already present or not if present it give me record but it goes in else part also and print else part.

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong in my code.

Comment: `SELECT Col1 FROM #TEST WHERE Col1 = 'aBc' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` for case sensitve query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `for` loop inside the `foreach` loop, so no wonder it's returned double result. You could remove the `for` loop :

```
public function fetchDue(){

  $due         = $this->input->post('due_to');
  $br          = $this->session->userdata('user_branch');
  $modelResult = $this->DDModel->fetchDue($due,$br);


  ?>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
    <table id="cash_memo_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="display:block; overflow: auto; ">

                <tr>
                  <th>mr_no</th>
                  <th>bilty_no</th>
                  <th>Bilty Date</th>
                  <th>Weight</th>
                  <th>Total</th> 
                  <th>Create/Update</th>
                </tr>


  <?php foreach ($modelResult as $i => $due) { // <---------------------- changed here
      $vfDueResult = $this->DDModel->verifyFetchDue($modelResult[$i]->mr_no);
       if($vfDueResult==1){
        ?>

        <?php

      }else if($vfDueResult==0){
          $verifyRemainingFetchDue  = $this->DDModel->verifyRemainingFetchDue($modelResult[$i]->mr_no);
          if($verifyRemainingFetchDue==1){
            $modelResult = $this->DDModel->fetchDDRRecord($modelResult[$i]->mr_no);

            ?>
                <tr>

                  <td><?php echo $due->mr_no; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->mr_no; ?>" name="mr_no[]">
                  <td><?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?>" name="bilty_no[]">
                  <td><?php echo $due->lr_date; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_date; ?>" name="lr_date[]">
                  <td><?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight ; ?></td> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight; ?>" name="lr_actual_weight[]">
                  <td><input type="hidden" class="cal" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $due->total; ?>"><?php echo $due->total; ?></td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-update" id="update">Update</button></td>
                </tr> 
                <?php

            }else{

               ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $due->mr_no; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->mr_no; ?>" name="mr_no[]">
                  <td><?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->bilty_no; ?>" name="bilty_no[]">
                  <td><?php echo $due->lr_date; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_date; ?>" name="lr_date[]">
                  <td><?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight ; ?></td> 
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $due->lr_actual_weight; ?>" name="lr_actual_weight[]">
                  <td><input type="hidden" class="cal" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $due->total; ?>"><?php echo $due->total; ?></td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-insert" id="insert">Insert</button></td>
                </tr> 
        <?php 
           }//else end
      }
   }
  ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form> 
<?php
}
```

Comment: Hi @KhanMuntazar you could mark as accepted answer if it's correct, or let me know if it's incorrect